# Minimizing number of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, minimization

The problem is about arranging a league consisting of small tournaments with 3 teams in each tournament, such that every team plays every other team the same amount of times (>0), with a minimum amount of tournaments.

If n teams are about to play each other one time it requires (n-1)+(n-2)+...+1 games. Each tournament consists of 3 games. In the case of 7 teams we would have 21 games. 21 mod 3 = 0 so it should be sufficient with each team playing each other 1 time:

```
 (1, 2, 3)
 (2, 4, 6)
 (3, 4, 7)
 (4, 5, 1)
 (5, 7, 2)
 (6, 3, 5)
 (7, 1, 6)
```

If we add 1 more team so that we have 8 teams, 21+7=28 games are required. But 28 mod 3 = 1 so we need to have each team play each other 3 times make it even.

It's easy to create the complete graph:

```
from itertools import combinations

tournaments = list(combinations(range(1,n+1),3))
games = [ [(x[0],x[1]),(x[0],x[2]),(x[1],x[2])] for x in tournaments ]
```

For n = 7 this will generate:

```
7! / (3!*(7-3)!) = 35
```

tournaments. In general:

```
n! / (n!*(n-3)!)
```

However, as shown above, for n = 7 it is sufficient with only 7 tournaments. Testing all combinations soon becomes unpractical. For n=7 we've seen that there is a maximum of 35 tournaments, but the power set of 35 elements contains 2^35=34359738368 combinations.

I'm looking for a way to either reduce the complete set of tournaments to a minimum amount or to construct it bottom up. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: `each tournament consists of 3 games.` `every team plays every other team the same amount of times` How is it even possible to satisfy all these conditions ? If team `A` plays team `B` one time, it requires all other teams playing team `A` and team `B`. Or am I mistaken ?

Comment: My explanation might be inadequate, but from the example with 7 teams we can see that team 1 plays against 2,3,4,5,6,7 exactly once (tournament 1,4 and 7). Team 2 participates in tournament 1,2 and 5 and plays against all other teams exactly once as well. The same holds for teams 3,4,5,6 and 7.

Comment: I edited to slowly so I'll add another comment. In the example above it is sufficient to play 7 tournaments to satisfy the criterias. For 8 teams a minimum of 27 tournaments is required where each team will have to play each other 3 times.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but try googling "combinatorial design".